# Calling a wordpress widget

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

I am having some problems while calling my `news` widget. It works fine when I call it in my header but didn't work in any other files like `page.php`, `home.php`. here is the simple code.

```
<?php  if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar("news") ) : ?><?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show the `news` widget using `dynamic_sidebar` function then try this

```
<?php  
    if ( function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') && dynamic_sidebar("news") ) :
    else :
     // static hard coded widgets
    endif;
?>
```

Comment: @MoeedFarooqui, `!` , if not function_exists || not `dynamic_sidebar("news")`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the sidebar widget in you page.php calling `get_sidebar` which will load the `sidebar-news.php` if you have register the widget in news sidebar so  simple call the sidebar which will load all the widgets in this sidebar

```
<?php get_sidebar( 'news' ); ?>
```